# Pig script to extract rows if columns has value that is part of list

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script like this

```
a = load 'large_file' using PigStorage(',')
b = filter a by $16 = '12345678'
c = filter a by $16 = '456'
d = union b,c 
store d into 'output.csv'
```

If i would like to filter a by a list of values. For example, I want to extract all rows when the 16th column has a value that is in a large list of values.

In pandas terms it would be

```
df[df['col'].isin([one massive list])]
```

I am using pig version 0.8

Answer (score 1):

For Pig-0.8, use multiple **`OR`** in the FILTER

```
b = filter a by $16 == '12345678' OR $16 == '456' OR $16 == 'anotherval';
```

Starting from Pig-0.12.0, you can use **`IN`** operator

```
b = filter a by $16 IN ('12345678', '456', ... );
```

Comment: @franklinsijio Is there anyway i can read the list from a file or something?

Comment: @aceminer If the list is in a file, the easier approach would be is to use [`replicated joins`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/perf.html#replicated-joins)

Comment: @franklinsjio It seems that replicated join only works for small files?

Comment: I assumed the file containing list will be smaller than the actual data file, in that case replicated joins perform better, else you can get it done with join. either way join will be the solution.